# How to use a web-worker from an npm library into main webpack project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, web-worker

My project structure is like this:

moduleA -> Library that i publish to npm using Rollup

projectA -> My gatsby project that installs moduleA and uses it.

I'm using this library to bundle my workers with my other library code into the dist folder: https://github.com/darionco/rollup-plugin-web-worker-loader

Module A code:

workers/index.js

```js
let webWorker = null;

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  webWorker = new Worker(new URL("./my.worker.js", import.meta.url), {
    type: "module",
  });
}

export default webWorker;
```

workers/my.worker.js

```js
self.onmessage = (message) => {
  console.log("hii");
  self.postMessage("yes");
};
```

When I build the above library the result is this:

[image]

So you can see that the workers are correctly in the library's dist now. This all works great.

If we take a look into `index.modern.module.js` you can see this is the output for the worker code:

```js
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  webWorker = new Worker(new URL("my.worker-f73c7cd4.js", import.meta.url), {
    type: "module"
  });
}
```

Now in my main project I have this webpack rule to convert the `import.meta.url` to a path otherwise webpack crashes as it does not recognize `import.meta.url`:

```js
 config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loader: require.resolve("@open-wc/webpack-import-meta-loader"),
});
```

I now run my main react project (which is built in gatsby & webpack) and this is the output in `index.modern.module.js`:

```js
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  webWorker = new Worker(new URL("my.worker-8e6a623b.js", ({ url: getAbsoluteUrl('node_modules/@tracktak/dcf-react/dist/index.modern.module.js') }).url), {
    type: "module"
  });
}
```

Here's the network request, you can see it loans in but I'm pretty sure the path is wrong. It's just saying a 200 ok because it's going to 404 page I think:

[image]

And it gives me a console error:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

So, my question is. How do I load the web worker to the public folder for my Gatsby project (projectA). Do I need to use something like `worker-loader` here? I'm just not sure how it can work here because it's in my npm module and NOT in my project.

Any help would be great and I'd award a bounty!

Thanks

EDIT: It seems like [worker-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin) is getting my closer to the solution. If I use this in my main project and modify the web workers in the dist output from this: `new URL("my.worker-8e6a623b.js", ({ url: getAbsoluteUrl('node_modules/@tracktak/dcf-react/dist/index.modern.module.js') }).url)` to this: `new URL("my.worker-8e6a623b.js")` it works fine as worker-plugin only accepts string arguments.

However this isn't a sustainable solution because obviously I don't want to modify dist files.

Comment: What does the network tab's "Preview" reveal? is it the code?

Comment: @DanLevy It says: 'Failed to load response data'. Which means it's very likely not loading the worker script at all, but instead loading a html webpage I think. So my path in the worker constructor seems wrong. I had a question on your answer though

Comment: Are you open to a simple solution instead your plugins?

Comment: @JRichardsz Absolutely. I'm open to simple solutions. Even if it doesn't solve it fully it would be great because I'm so lost with this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated:

Verify the dist folder contents are correct. I'm surprised to see files from old builds (multiple hash ids). Clean folder, then generate all scripts (for performance reasons, you might want to only do this on production builds.)

Then when you `npm publish` the files, verify npm picked up what you expect.

There's an alternate way to make sure it's not related to npm's selective file bundling. Use the GitHub repo URL to `npm install <github repo URL>`.

#### Original response:

I believe you need `worker-loader`.

I've used `comlink` & `worker-loader` to help smooth over Webpack worker bundling.

Comment: But worker-loader requires you to import the worker like this:

import MyWorker from './my.worker.js`

const worker = new MyWorker()

I think anyway, so how can I do that if I don't have access to the code as it's in my node module dist bundle?

Comment: I'm looking for some similar code I recently did in this project: https://github.com/justsml/DataAnalyzer.app/search?q=worker

Comment: I'm realizing I hacked a solution around this... I copied my library into the main project folder, got rid of the different build tools (rollup & webpack). 
My plan was to keep the library package.json so I could still maintain the package on NPM - just a slightly different CLI publish process.

Comment: In this process I found several helpful resources - I'll see if I can find my notes; I did oh so much research around this.

Comment: Here's a GitHub issue comment I specifically linked to: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6472#issuecomment-781705208

Comment: thanks I'll take a look soon at the links. In response to your update, their is not old build files in my dist. It's build files for different environment, e.g. modern, es, cjs, amd, etc that's why there's multiple hashes

Comment: So I looked at the links, unfortunately I can't figure out how it can help me.

I can't modify the node module file because other teams need to have a reproducible way of using it. Also, that second issue comment link I am already using import.meta.url in the worker.

Comment: I feel your pain, it took me weeks to even get it working in 1 repo. I still want to get the project & library separate again. I wonder if example projects could be found by searching github for webpack config files targeting 'webworker.' (I know it's not needed since v5, but it might yield useful leads.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dan. I checked my webpack version and I'm using 4.x instead of 5.x. Does 4.x need anything different? The reason is I'm using Gatsby which uses 4.x under the hood.